# Self Deleting Executable (Uninstaller)

Tags: c#, uninstallation

I'm trying to make an uninstaller. 
I basically need to be able to remove a directory in the program files that contains the uninstaller.

I was thinking to have the uninstaller create a copy of itself to the temp folder, 
then have the uninstaller running from the program folder open the uninstaller in temp and close itself where it continues the uninstall.

Problem is, how do I delete the uninstaller in the temp folder...

Comment: MSI uninstalls programs.  You don't delete msiexec.exe.  Simple to get going with a Setup project, avoid re-inventing that wheel.

Comment: Got it, but I'd prefer it my way though. How could I go about doing something like a self-deleting exe

Comment: You can create an install project in Visual Studio.  Else you can run a bat-file to run your executable and afterward deleting the executable, bat-file and folder.

Comment: A self-deleting EXE is going to set off every virus scanner known to man. This isn't a good idea for an *installer*, especially when that problem has been solved.

Comment: @CodyGray: Funny, but NSIS uninstallers have no such issue.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Even though I agree with everyone saying you shouldn't do that, what you can do is:

1. Have your program create an executable (and config file) in the temporary folder of the OS it's working on.
2. Have your program start it as an independent process, then exit.
3. That executable then calls back the actual setup stuff.
4. Once the setup is done, the temporary executable can delete the setup files.
5. Since the only trace of your program is now in the temp folder, it will **eventually** get cleared automatically.

Comment: The temp folder doesn't get cleared automatically. https://superuser.com/questions/318497/do-files-in-the-temporary-folders-get-automatically-deleted

Answer (score 2):

Check out: https://www.catch22.net/tuts/win32/self-deleting-executables

He has multiple solutions - but mostly aimed at C++ code.

I am currently trying to implement the "DELETE_ON_CLOSE" method in C#.

**A comment to all the nay-sayers:** MSI does not solve this problem in all cases.  In my case, my application needs to install to a network folder, where any network user can run the app.  It also needs to support upgrades and uninstalls from any network workstation - not necessarily the same workstation that installed the app.  This means I cannot register an Uninstaller into the Add/Remove Programs list on the local machine.  I must create an Uninstall.exe that is dropped into the install folder.  MSI does not support that, so I have to write my own.